# Android layout too big on some devices

Tags: android, layout

My apps layout looks fine on my device and any device I tested it so far. The layout has some seekbars with a fixed dp width and a textview beside it. 
But now I saw a screenshot from another device and the text is cut off, because the graphics appear so big.
This surprises me because they are normally fittingly resized depending on the density bucket (designed for xxhdpi) and I did never see this problem before. Maybe the device is just on the edge of a density bucket? Is there a certain dp width that I shouldn't exceed?
I don't know what would cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the border margin in dimens.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can do certain things to solve this.

1. As @yashetty29 suggested
2. If its only the text problem you can forcefully set that text size in dp and not sp. Many users makes device font size larger ( like my dad :p ) that makes weird looking UI.
3. or you can use this library. It may help you.

SSP: for text (sp values) -> https://github.com/intuit/ssp

SDP: for text (dp values) -> https://github.com/intuit/sdp